# Firebase deploy could not locate firebase.json

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

so, im a newbie in programming and still learning some stuff (i use windows btw)

i try to make an app, connect it to firebase.
after setting up everything its time to setting the CLI

**good news** : i successfully setting up everything from node to nvm untill sucessfully launch the login in CLI.

**bad news** : right after successfully logn the CLI, im trying to type in the cmd

**firebase deploy --only function**

and this error appear

**Error: not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)**

i already search the web for the solution but i found nothing

can someone tell me did i miss something ? 
thanks.

Comment: have you done: "firebase init" yet?

Comment: Without the exact list of instructions that you followed to get to this point, we can only speculate.  The detail should be great enough that anyone can reproduce the error you're seeing.

Comment: omg.. yes i forgot the init.. thanks guys.. now its working

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After logging into firebase with `firebase login` you will need to do: `firebase init` and then select the correct options when prompted. be sure to press the space bar to check the functions circle in the command line.

Answer (score 6):

```
firebase init
```

or

```
firebase init hosting
```

And then popup question:
Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? **No**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`firebase init` didn't work for me, but `firebase init hosting` did. You can read the firebase hosting initialization docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart#initialize).

Comment: created the firebase.json for me. Worked thanks

Answer (score -1):

After running the **firebase login** command, do not delete the `Firebase CLI Login Successful` page in the browser and then run the **firebase init** command from the command line.