# Firebase CLI not working (firebase deploy)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have setup my firebase cloud functions and CLI correctly and deployed my function for the first time already and all worked fine.

Now that I closed the command prompt and ran it again, firebase does not recognize my project. When I run firebase deploy it give me this Error: "Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Are you calling it from the directory above your functions directory? Usually when you call `firebase init` it will link your project and list the different items you want to deploy. I would check your parent directory for a firebase.json folder and if one does not exist, I would then call `firebase init` in the parent directory. (Backup your functions folder first)

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question.please check

Answer (score 1):

Firebase automatically creates your `firebase.json` file at the root of your project directory when you run the `firebase init` command.

After logging into firebase with `firebase login` you will need to do: `firebase init` and then select the correct options when prompted. be sure to press the space bar to check the functions circle in the command line.you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820813/firebase-deploy-could-not-locate-firebase-json).

`firebase login` and `firebase init` will  initialize the file `firebase.json`.
Also, run `firebase deploy` inside the root directory of the project folder where `firebase.json` lives..

You can follow the video tutorial  in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)  which might help you.